# PHP use dynamic variables from function in script?

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a function that reads a config file and then makes variables from the values in the file.

$arr is an array of values read from a text file and then this is turned into variables.

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  ${$k} = trim($v);
}
```

This is all done within a function. However I'd like to use the variables created elsewhere in the page. As they are dynamically created I don't know what they will all be called.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can I use them outside of the function ? if so how ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm not following the goal.

Comment: you are missing an `as` between in you `foreach`

Comment: The `as` is in my code, I missed it when I typed it in on here..

Comment: The goal is to have the variables created in the function available to the rest of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array where you would keep all your options and make it `global` in your function and then all the options will accessible inside and outside of the function. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) out.

Comment: I had thought about that - but as it's dynamic I won't know what values are in the array or what order they are in.

Comment: Give every option a key and a value and when you save them in an array you save them like `$options[$option_name] = $option_value;`

Comment: How do I make the array available to the rest of the page ?

Comment: OK I've sorted it... and it looks like this will work for me :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Push them all in an array in your function and get the array elsewhere.